# Group, count, and copy by multiple field values in excel programatically

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

Hi I have a spreadsheet that I need to count and group based on multiple values. Using the example below I need it to count a row only if Shipper - Shipper city, Recipient, and Recipient city are all the same. Otherwise I need it to create a new entry.

In addition to the count I have to do it programatically if possible rather than using a pivot table because it will be updated from a SQL DB frequently and controlled by various users through buttons. I have used VBA to get the data here, but I lost as to how to move forward with the sort/grouping.

I have tried a for loop with nested conditionals but am quite new to VBA so I have had little success.

How the table currently looks;

```
# - Shipper - City -  Recipient - City     -   Bool
1   Bob       L.A.    Jenny      Las Vegas    True
2   Bob       L.A.    Jenny      Las Vegas    False
3   Bob       L.A.    Jenny      Portland     True
4   Bob       L.A     Jenny      Orem         True
5   Bob       L.A     Jenny      Orem         True
6   Sam       L.A     Jenny      Portland     True
7   Sam       L.A     Jenny      Portland     True
8   Sam       L.A     Jenny      Reno         False
9   Sam       L.A     Jenny      Reno         False
```

The end result should be on a new sheet;

```
# - Shipper - City -  Recipient - City     -   Count - Bool
1   Bob       L.A.    Jenny      Las Vegas      2     50%
2   Bob       L.A.    Jenny      Portland       1     100%
3   Bob       L.A.    Jenny      Orem           2     100%
4   Sam       L.A     Jenny      Portland       2     100%
5   Sam       L.A     Jenny      Reno           2     0%
```

Comment: you can create a pivot table and use VBA to replace the original tables instead of creating new file every time.. also,, what have you tried and did not work?

Comment: Which Excel Version are you using?

Comment: If you are using xl2007+ then I can suggest a very simple code for you...

Comment: @SiddharthRout - I am using excel 2007.

Comment: Ok. will post the code then. One quick question though... What if in the main data, `Orem' has 2 Trues and 1 False. what should be the Bool % in the final outcome

Comment: @SiddharthRout Just an percentage of true values so %66.666666... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your data looks like this

[image]

All you have to do now is paste the below code in a module and run it. The output will be displayed in a new sheet. You do not have to worry about increase/decreasing rows in your data. Simply ensure that the data is in Cols A to E and from 1st row as shown in the screenshot above. Else you will have to amend the macro.

**LOGIC (What the code does)**:

1. Copy Col `A-D` only to a new sheet
2. Use the inbuilt `.RemoveDuplicates` to remove excessive data
3. Use `COUNTIFS()` to count the number of records and display in Col E
4. Then again use `COUNTIFS()` to count the number of `TRUE` and display in Col `F`
5. Use `COUNTIFS()` to count the number of `FALSE` and display in Col `G`
6. In Col `H`, find the percentage. Once done, convert it to values
7. Delete Col F and Col G
8. Format Col `G` (now Col `F`) to `%`

**CODE**:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add

    With wsOutput
        ws.Range("A:D").Copy .Range("A:D")

        .Range("A:D").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4), Header:=xlYes

        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("E2:E" & lRow).Formula = "=COUNTIFS(" & ws.Name & "!A:A,A2," & _
                                                       ws.Name & "!B:B,B2," & _
                                                       ws.Name & "!C:C,C2," & _
                                                       ws.Name & "!D:D,D2)"

        .Range("F2:F" & lRow).Formula = "=COUNTIFS(" & ws.Name & "!A:A,A2," & _
                                                       ws.Name & "!B:B,B2," & _
                                                       ws.Name & "!C:C,C2," & _
                                                       ws.Name & "!D:D,D2," & _
                                                       ws.Name & "!E:E,""TRUE"")"

        .Range("G2:G" & lRow).Formula = "=COUNTIFS(" & ws.Name & "!A:A,A2," & _
                                                       ws.Name & "!B:B,B2," & _
                                                       ws.Name & "!C:C,C2," & _
                                                       ws.Name & "!D:D,D2," & _
                                                       ws.Name & "!E:E,""FALSE"")"

        .Range("H2:H" & lRow).Formula = "=F2/SUM(F2:G2)"
        .Range("H2:H" & lRow).Value = .Range("H2:H" & lRow).Value

        .Columns("F:G").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        .Columns("F:F").NumberFormat = "0%"
        .Cells(1, 5).Value = "Count": .Cells(1, 6).Value = "BOOL"
    End With
End Sub
```

**OUTPUT**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. This did it. I had to adjust a little bit because the actual tables are much larger but this did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

You can use SUMPRODUCT function, for example

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A500="Bob")*(B1:B500="L.A")*(D1:D500="Las Vegas")*1)
```

Pivot Table is a good option too...

[]´s

Comment: With SUMPRODUCT, do I have to know the values I am grouping in advance, or is there a way to make it dynamic with each sheet. This is going to be run over many tables with alot of data. I need to be able to group only if all 4 fields match.

Comment: You can use AdvancedFilter Method to get unique values, and use sumproduct function on VBA to group this information.